# android, Shared Library

Tags: android, usb

I'm Developing an Android app to communicate with a USB peripheral, The App is designed for a non-commercial purpose so it is gonna run only on  a Samsung Galaxy young with Android 2.3.5.

After a bit of searching i used the Google APIs add-on library com.android.future.usb i went through the tutorial on the code.android website 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html

but when i deployed the app on the Galaxy y it came up with the " INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY"   corresponding to the  tag in the .xml file from my understanding  that appears if the phone doesn't include this shared lib specifically as at the end of the day the .jar is not gonna be added to the .apk file and it's just a stub to develop your application but the complete lib should be installed already on your Android, and Galaxy y with Android 2.3.5 doesn't come with that shared lib com.android.future.usb

Is there a way to overcome this problem or what to do to communicate with a USB peripheral on that Phone?!!

Thanks in Advance.